# What's the expected behavior of stack protection with statically-sized arrays?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, assembly

If I compile the following in Ubuntu 16.04 / gcc 7.3

```
struct VecA {
  float data[4];
};

struct VecB {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  float w;
};

// Requires stack protection
VecA getA() {return {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};}

// Does not require stack protection
VecB getB() {return {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};}
```

Like so:

```
g++ -O3 -c -o result test.cpp
objdump -d result
```

I get:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z4getAv>:
   0:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
   4:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   b:   00 00 
   d:   48 89 44 24 08          mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
  12:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  14:   f3 0f 7e 05 00 00 00    movq   0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 1c <_Z4getAv+0x1c>
  1b:   00 
  1c:   48 8b 44 24 08          mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
  21:   64 48 33 04 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
  28:   00 00 
  2a:   75 09                   jne    35 <_Z4getAv+0x35>
  2c:   66 0f 6f c8             movdqa %xmm0,%xmm1
  30:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  34:   c3                      retq   
  35:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  3a <_Z4getAv+0x3a>
  3a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000000040 <_Z4getBv>:
  40:   f3 0f 7e 05 00 00 00    movq   0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 48 <_Z4getBv+0x8>
  47:   00 
  48:   66 0f 6f c8             movdqa %xmm0,%xmm1
  4c:   c3                      retq
```

Which "looks" like linux stack protection is being applied to `VecA`. A little bit on the defensive side, but I can understand how a compiler could reach that conclusion.

However, This is where i'm getting confused:

I can't reproduce this on godbolt.org, even with stack protection explicitly on. I can make it happen for BOTH functions with `-fstack-protector-all` but that's expected, and uninteresting.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ePR98P

Also, it seems that, on my system, explicitly using the stack protector is removing the protection from `getA()`

```
g++ -O3 -c -o -fstack-protector result test.cpp
objdump -d result

0000000000000000 <_Z4getAv>:
   0:   f3 0f 7e 05 00 00 00    movq   0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 8 <_Z4getAv+0x8>
   7:   00 
   8:   66 0f 6f c8             movdqa %xmm0,%xmm1
   c:   c3                      retq   
   d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)

0000000000000010 <_Z4getBv>:
  10:   f3 0f 7e 05 00 00 00    movq   0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 18 <_Z4getBv+0x8>
  17:   00 
  18:   66 0f 6f c8             movdqa %xmm0,%xmm1
  1c:   c3                      retq
```

So my questions are:

1. Why are my local results that much different than what's being generated on godbolt.org?
2. Is there a reasonable explanation behind the behavior on my system? Especially regarding `-fstack-protector` removing protection.
3. It is reasonable to assert that both functions should be generating equivalent assembly in optimized code?

**Edit**:

Full version string:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: C++ has no concept of "stack protection" - this is entirely a GCC feature. Arguably, the `c++` tag should be removed.

Comment: @NeilButterworth On the other hand, the question is about specific C++ code examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The default on Ubuntu's gcc is `-fstack-protector-strong`**, not `-fstack-protector-all`.  ([The gcc manual lists available options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)).

https://lwn.net/Articles/584225/ describes "strong".  It really likes to protect arrays, but structs with no array members can't be indexed so there's much less chance of overflow.

[On Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'struct+VecA+%7B%0A++float+data%5B4%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+VecB+%7B%0A++float+x%3B%0A++float+y%3B%0A++float+z%3B%0A++float+w%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A//+Requires+stack+protection%0AVecA+getA()+%7Breturn+%7B1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f%7D%3B%7D%0A%0A//+Does+not+require+stack+protection%0AVecB+getB()+%7Breturn+%7B1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f%7D%3B%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.69370508264983,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B14++-fstack-protector-strong+-O3+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:30.97296158401685,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fstack-protector',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), that produces stack protection for VecA but not VecB, like on your desktop.  (And BTW, you can use `g++ -S -masm=intel -O3` to get Intel-syntax, or `objdump -drwC -Mintel`, since you linked to Intel-syntax on Godbolt.)

You can use `g++ -S -fverbose-asm -O3 foo.cpp` to include comments showing all the implied and explicit options gcc used when compiling.  On Godbolt, uncheck the `//` icon to not hide asm comments, [like this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'struct+VecA+%7B%0A++float+data%5B4%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+VecB+%7B%0A++float+x%3B%0A++float+y%3B%0A++float+z%3B%0A++float+w%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A//+Requires+stack+protection%0AVecA+getA()+%7Breturn+%7B1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f%7D%3B%7D%0A%0A//+Does+not+require+stack+protection%0AVecB+getB()+%7Breturn+%7B1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f,+1.0f%7D%3B%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.69370508264983,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'1',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B14++-fstack-protector-strong+-O3+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:30.97296158401685,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fstack-protector',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

```
# GNU C++14 (GCC-Explorer-Build) version 7.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
#       compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.16.1-GMP

# GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
# options passed:  -fdiagnostics-color=always -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu
# -iprefix /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/
# -D_GNU_SOURCE
# /tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler11885-54-1u26why.tdoy/example.cpp
# -masm=intel -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
# -auxbase-strip /tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler11885-54-1u26why.tdoy/output.s
# -g -O3 -std=gnu++14 -fstack-protector-strong -fverbose-asm
# options enabled:  -faggressive-loop-optimizations -falign-labels
# -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg
# -fcaller-saves -fchkp-check-incomplete-type -fchkp-check-read
# -fchkp-check-write -fchkp-instrument-calls -fchkp-narrow-bounds
# -fchkp-optimize -fchkp-store-bounds -fchkp-use-static-bounds
# -fchkp-use-static-const-bounds -fchkp-use-wrappers -fcode-hoisting
# -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcommon -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers
# -fcrossjumping -fcse-follow-jumps -fdefer-pop
...
```

Comment: Ahhh. that's my mistake, I thought the default was `-fstack-protector` for some reason.